# How do you get all the post request variables in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting a post from an external vendor.  I am not exactly sure what variables they are sending.  How do I print out all the Request variables that they are sending in the post?  there is no Request.Count or Request.Length so that I could loop and find everything.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get it from Request.Forms

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys ) 
{
  Response.Write ( key );
}
```

Comment: This will print out only the values of each key POSTed to your server. If you need to also print out the key portion, just invoke `Response.Write(key);` - :)

Answer (score 18):

The [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) property contains a collection with all form fields. It is a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) which implements `ICollection` so you should be able to loop it with `foreach`. `Request.Form.Keys` will give you all the form field names, then you can use that name to look up the value.

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
  Response.Write(key + ": " + Request.Form[key] + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to loop through the `Request.Form` (if you know it will always be in the Form collection).

Check out this MSDN link for an example on how to iterate through Request.Form:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx

Or the following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please iterate Request.Form and you will see the name and value of the variables